# Store a string in a vector of unsigned long int

Tags: c++

I would like to convert a `std::string` into a `std::vector<unsigned long int>`, and be able to reverse it. Currently, I do this by this way :

```
std::string str = "Hello World !";
std::vector<unsigned long int> keys;
for(unsigned long int i = 0; i < str.length();)
{
  unsigned long int key = 0;
  for(unsigned long int j = 0; j < sizeof(unsigned long int) && i < str.length(); ++i,++j)
  {
    unsigned char uchar_value = static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]);
    unsigned long int ulong_value = static_cast<unsigned long int>(uchar_value);
    key |= ulong_value << (j * CHAR_BIT);
  }
  keys.push_back(key);
}
```

Then, I have a similar procedure to reverse it. But it's quite ugly ! **Is there a better/more elegant way to do it ?** Maybe directly with `memcpy` ? But I don't see how.

Comment: I'd be inclined to just use `memcpy`, if you don't care about endian issues when accessing groups of `char`s as `unsigned long`s.  What's the point of this, anyway?  Couldn't you just type-pun a pointer into the `std::string` data, instead of copying?  Or parse the decimal or hex digits into binary "limbs", and store those in the key vector?

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
std::string str = "Hello World !";
std::vector<unsigned long int> keys(str.size() / sizeof(unsigned long int)+1);

std::copy(begin(str), end(str), reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(*keys.begin())));
```

And the reverse:

```
std::string str2(keys.size()*sizeof(unsigned long int), '\0');
std::copy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&*begin(keys)), reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&*end(keys)), str2.begin());
str2.resize(str.size());
```

And if you want to store the bytes in reverse order, you can use reverse iterators:

```
std::string str = "Hello World !";
std::vector<unsigned long int> keys(str.size() / sizeof(unsigned long int)+1);

std::copy(str.rbegin(), str.rbegin, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(*keys.begin())));
```

Answer (score -2):

First I would use Linked List because insertion to beginning and end is O(1). I don't understand why you would have a problem casting `char` to `unsigned long int` that you are doing casts and binary operations... Here is the code that does forward and reverse using `std::list`.

```
std::string str = "Hello World";
std::list<unsigned long int> keys;

for(char x : str) {
    unsigned long int c = (unsigned long int) x;
    // keys.push_back(c); // forward
    keys.push_front(c); // reverse
}
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/jZxKmy)

EDIT: And here is using `std::vector` if using vector is required. So the inner loop logic is going to be the same, only the iterator direction will change:

```
// forward
for(std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
    unsigned long int c = (unsigned long int) (*it);
    keys.push_back(c);
}

// reverse
for(std::string::reverse_iterator it = str.rbegin(); it != str.rend(); ++it) {
    unsigned long int c = (unsigned long int) (*it);
    keys.push_back(c);
}
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/1sn5tF)

Comment: `deque` will probably be better than `list`

Comment: When you cast a negative char to an unsigned long int, you obtain a big number, and not a number between 0 and 255.

Comment: Yeah but we are talking about string characters. So we can safely assume that, there wouldn't be negative characters.

Comment: The string is a RSA key. Actually, they are negatives.

Comment: Even with signed char, all the ASCII characters are positive, because they're in the 0-127 range.  So not an ideal solution, but it should be fine for storing text representations of ASCII keys.  If you cast to uint8_t first, you'd ensure zero-extension rather than sign-extension.  Still, you're wasting a lot of space storing one char per long, but it's not clear whether memcpy-like behaviour was a requirement for the OP.