# Convert each byte of an unsigned long to an element of an unsigned char array

Tags: c, char, type-conversion, long-integer, unsigned

If I have this `unsigned long x` (4 bytes), how I could convert each byte of the `x` in its hexadecimal equivalent and store all of them in the array:  `unsigned char[4]`?

**UPDATE**

Based on then sugestions I got, I have tried this two solutions:

solution 1:

```
  unsigned char hex_str[9];
  snprintf(hex_str, sizeof(hex_str), "%lX", target_hexstr);
  printf("hex_str: %s\n", hex_str);
  printf("size: %lu\n", sizeof(hex_str));
  for(int x=0; x<sizeof(hex_str); x++)
    printf("%x\n", hex_str[x]);
```

in this case, `hex_str` displays `1400` and 9 "units":  31, 34, 30, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24.

solution 2:

```
  hexstr[0] = (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
  printf("%x\n", x[0]);
  hexstr[1] = (hexstr & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
  printf("%x\n", x[1]);
  hexstr[2] = (hexstr & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
  printf("%x\n", x[2]);
  hexstr[3] = (hexstr & 0x000000FF);
  printf("%x\n", x[3]);
  printf("hex_str: %s\n", hex_str);
```

in this case, `hex_str` display nothing and 4 "units": 0, 0, 14, 0.

Why this 2 solutions have differents results?

Answer (score 2):

Because i like bitwise operations iam gonna show you what i would do. But @BLUEPIXY's solution is way more elegant.

We will need

- `&` bitwise and
- `>>` bitwise shift right

Here is the simple solution, where we are expecting `UL` as `4B`.

```
unsigned long x = 42;
unsigned char uc[4];

uc[0] = (x & 0x000000FF);
uc[1] = (x & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
uc[2] = (x & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
uc[3] = (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

printf("uc[0] = %x \n", uc[0]);
printf("uc[1] = %x \n", uc[1]);
printf("uc[2] = %x \n", uc[2]);
printf("uc[3] = %x \n", uc[3]);
```

Comment: Do you can tell what's the difference he order of the index ould have? For instance, in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30840656/2692962, I think the order is the reverse of the yours.

Comment: Its exactly the same with little different syntax.

Comment: Please don't supply code where there was no attempt shown.

Comment: @FilipKočica I update some code I have tried (based on the 2 sugestions I got), and got differents results. Do you know why this happen?

Comment: @FilipKočica easy for *you* and you are keen but please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) OP refers to a previous question, mentions the code does not work. We need to see OP's code to be helpful.

Comment: But as you can see he tried :-) @KleberMota UL has 4Bytes. It means result should have 8 hexa characters so your first attempt is wrong.

Comment: Yes, but only after prompting.

Comment: Ok i will read this link and hopefuly next time i'll do better :-)

Comment: Oh sorry: the OP has sufficient rep and a vast number of badges to have asked a better question.